# How to render proper names having a hidden overtone in their semantic structure as it has essential meaning for prose fiction?

Tags: multiple-languages

Should a translator create a new name using a potential of the target language and save its meaning, or omit this feature applying method of traditional transliteration?

Comment: Could you add some examples?

Comment: This question seems to relate more to translation between languages than actually learning languages.